# comparison between mqtt and coap using omnetpp

Tags: mqtt, omnet++, coap

I want to compare MQTT and CoAP application layer protocols on reliability and power consumption in simulator: omnetpp.

Does **Omnetpp** support these two protocols?

Is there any existing open source project that I can check?

I watched a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cwe0M8TcNVA) and found that the author just have a simple parameter in the omnetpp.ini file: IOT.*.protocol = "MQTT" or "COAP".  This is not standard option right? I wonder what extra work has to be done.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

CoAP and MQTT models are not available for OMNeT++. In the video, the guy is definitely showing his own project. 
You can create the MQTT simulation model by modifying the TCP applications given in INET and use your own message class with MQTT payload.